# What is the difference between image registration and image alignment?

Tags: computer-vision, alignment, matching

I know that:

**Image Alignment**:
is the process of finding the spatial mapping, i.e. elements in one image into meaningful correspondence with elements in a second image.

And

**Image Registration**:
is the process of aligning two or more images of the same scene.

I don't see and difference between these two definitions, could anyone clarify the difference to me?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there is a formal distinction and both words are used interchangeably.

If you were to nit-pick, then finding a transformation from one image to another ("alignment" per your definition) is a distinct process than actually performing the image warping procedure ("registration" per your definition).

Often the transformation is what you need and warping is not always required.

Comment: I think this is correct - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration also mentions the two terms interchangeably.